# Chrome is loading my print stylesheet when in screen mode, is this a bug?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I was under the assumption that a print stylesheet would not get loaded when in the "screen" context, however, the stylesheet is still loading in Chrome (windows).  Is this a bug, am I tripping, or is my assumption incorrect that "print" should not load?

[image: chrome screenshoot]

Here is my html:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="all.css" type="text/css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print">
</head>
```

Using Chrome 24.0.1312.52 m (latest)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a bug. When you link to a stylesheet in the DOM it will make a server request and download it. The `media=screen`, `media=print` etc are conditions that apply ONLY to the styles inside the stylesheet - so you will never see your print.css styles applied on your screen (and vice-versa). It will not prevent your stylesheet from being loaded though. Now some browsers are known to defer the loading when you specify `media=print`, so that your page renders first and then the print.css is loaded - but not all browsers do that.

This blog entry [here](http://crisp.tweakblogs.net/blog/6441/lazy-loading-print-stylesheets-part-ii.html) by Crisp, explains how you can lazy-load your print stylesheet using javascript. This makes it so that it loads only when the user needs to print, unfortunately the method he uses (the `window.onbeforeprint` is only supported in IE and Firefox - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onbeforeprint.asp).

Comment: Is there a better way in 2017?

Comment: @Sebastian yes, have a look into `<link rel="preload">`

Comment: `<link rel="preload">` won't help here; that's used to signal the browser that it should load something earlier than it otherwise would, which is not what was being discussed.